# How to show data in React Table with structure {_id:" xx",timestamp:"xx" ,message:"{"temperature:22","humi":45}" }?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-table

**React-Table**
I have made an axios.get request to the back-end which in turn gives a large data-set from mongodb. The 
structure of data returned is :

```
[
1: {_id: "5dd3be2ecf55e1ec388f502b", timestamp: 1574157870567, message: "{"temperature":58,"humidity":59,"pressure":"1 bar"}"}
2: {_id: "5dd3be2ecf55e1ec388f502a", timestamp: 1574157870067, message: "{"temperature":78,"humidity":79,"pressure":"1 bar"}"}
...
]
```

I want to show it to react-table.The id and timestamp is being displayed but the temperature and other variable are not being displayed.
The message is string.How can I parse such amount of data at back-end to convert message into object?
**Back-end code**

```js
    router.get('/viewData',async(req,res) =>{
    collection.find({},{_id:0,timestamp:0}).sort({timestamp:-1}).limit(400).toArray(function (err, resultantData) {
            if (err)
                throw err;
            //var storedDataArray ;
            //var gotData=[];
            //var index =0;
            //storedDataArray=resultantData;
            //console.log(storedDataArray)
            // storedDataArray.forEach(element => {
            //     gotData[index]=JSON.parse(element);
            //     console.log(gotData[index])
            //     index++;
            // })
            // console.log(gotData.length);
           res.status(200).json(resultantData);
        });
```

Is there any way to show temperature and other quantities in react table?

React-Table

```js
class deviceData extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            dataList:[],
            data : ' '
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        const url="http://localhost:5000/api/data/viewData";
        fetch (url,{
            method: "GET"
        }).then(response=> response.json()).then(result=>{
            console.log(result);

           this.setState({
            dataList : result,

           });
        });
  }


    render() {
        const columns =[
            {
                Header:"Message ID",
                accessor:"_id",
                sortable: true,
                filterable: false,
                style:{
                    textAlign: "left"
                },
                width: 300,
                maxWidth: 100,
                minWidth: 100,
            },
            {
                Header:"Time Stamp",
                accessor:"timestamp",
                width: 300,
                maxWidth: 100,
                minWidth: 100,
            },
            {
                Header:"Temperature",
                id:'temperature',
                filterable: false,
                accessor: 'temperature'
            },
            {
                Header:"Pressure",
                id:'pressure',
                filterable: false,
                accessor: 'pressure'
            },
            {
                Header:"Humidity",
                id:'humidity',
                filterable: false,
                accessor: 'humidity'
            },




]
       return(
           <div className="ReactTable">
           <ReactTable
           columns={columns}
           data={this.state.dataList}
           defaultPageSize={10}
           className="-striped -highlight"
           >
           </ReactTable>
           <div id={"#"+ this.props.id} ></div>
           </div>

       );
    }
}
[![React-Table][1]][1]
```

Backend Response

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5dd3be2fcf55e1ec388f502c",
        "timestamp": 1574157871067,
        "message": "{\"temperature\":93,\"humidity\":94,\"pressure\":\"1 bar\"}"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5dd3be2ecf55e1ec388f502b",
        "timestamp": 1574157870567,
        "message": "{\"temperature\":58,\"humidity\":59,\"pressure\":\"1 bar\"}"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5dd3be2ecf55e1ec388f502a",
        "timestamp": 1574157870067,
        "message": "{\"temperature\":78,\"humidity\":79,\"pressure\":\"1 bar\"}"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5dd3be2dcf55e1ec388f5029",
        "timestamp": 1574157869567,
        "message": "{\"temperature\":88,\"humidity\":89,\"pressure\":\"1 bar\"}"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5dd3be2dcf55e1ec388f5028",
        "timestamp": 1574157869066,
        "message": "{\"temperature\":99,\"humidity\":100,\"pressure\":\"1 bar\"}"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5dd3be2ccf55e1ec388f5027",
        "timestamp": 1574157868567,
        "message": "{\"temperature\":38,\"humidity\":39,\"pressure\":\"1 bar\"}"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5dd3be2ccf55e1ec388f5026",
        "timestamp": 1574157868067,
        "message": "{\"temperature\":82,\"humidity\":83,\"pressure\":\"1 bar\"}"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5dd3be2bcf55e1ec388f5025",
        "timestamp": 1574157867566,
        "message": "{\"temperature\":76,\"humidity\":77,\"pressure\":\"1 bar\"}"
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you put here some of your `react` code that you try to show the table?

Comment: @tareqaziz I have added it.

Answer (score 0):

Convert string back to object by using `parse()`

ex: var object = JSON.parse(str);

Important thing is to define column with correct accessor. Try this one:

```
const columns = [
      {
        Header: "Id",
        accessor: "_id"
      },
      {
        Header: "timestamp",
        accessor: "timestamp"
      },
      {
        Header: "Temprature",
        accessor: "message.temprature"
      },
      {
        Header: "humidity",
        accessor: "message.humidity"
      },
      {
        Header: "pressure",
        accessor: "message.pressure"
      }   
    ];
```

And Use it in React-table like this:

```
<ReactTable
 data={loans}  // Instead of loans, use variable where you store your response 
 columns={columns}
 defaultPageSize={10}
 sortable={true}
/>
```

Comment: It's not accessible like this.The message object is having string type objects

Comment: Ok, please share your response. Otherwise, you can modify your response from backend which return an Array of Object.

Comment: I have added the server response

Comment: I have tried parsing the resultantData in the Back-end Code but its unable to parse, `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: OK I tried parsing every array, it got parsed.      ```storedDataArray.forEach(element => {
                gotData[index]=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(element))
                console.log(gotData[index].message);
                index++;
            });```

Comment: Its getting the values of the message but its still string but when  i again parse its showing `Unexpected token , in JSON at position 51`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try with adding a **`headers`** in your fetch method

```
fetch (url,{
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }
})
```

It will ensure your response is JSON

N.B. Try your url with postman first, setting those headers and see whether result is JSON or not, if it is JSON I believe my code will help you, if it is not a JSON return try to change your back-end code to ensure it return JSON using postman

Comment: It's in json format.Its working.The problem is that if I want to access the message key the values are returned ,NOTE HERE, the values are constaining another set of key values like temp,press.How can I get temp data from this and display in react-tabel? **P.S The message key is containing a string value of temp pressure etc.**

Comment: If you are able to reach `message` as string try `JSON.parse(message).temperature` or `JSON.parse(message).humidity` or `JSON.parse(message).pressure` to extract your required field's value

Comment: I have doubt .Can I parse message if it having structure like " {"key":"value"},...n ".

Comment: this is the result I am getting from api:`{"temperature":"43C","humidity":"44%","pressure":"1 bar","rain":"65mm","wind":"65km/hr"}
{"temperature":"28C","humidity":"29%","pressure":"1 bar","rain":"70mm","wind":"70km/hr"}` using `storedDataArray.forEach(element => {
                 gotData[index]=JSON.parse(element);
                 console.log(gotData[index])
                 index++;
            })`